# How to Query value and filter data with value only?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am using a query formula to import data from a different sheet. However, after querying the data, I only need it to show data with value only. How to remove data without value when I query?

My query formula is the following:

```
=QUERY(Paste!A:G,"SELECT A,B,C,D WHERE B ='"&$C$6&"' or B ='"&$C$7&"' or B ='"&$C$8&"' or B ='"&$C$9&"' or B ='"&$C$10&"' or B ='"&$C$11&"' ORDER BY D DESC")
```

My spreadsheet link is the following:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A6lGIlU147Y_0WFD7Btkq4IMuY-Z3D1HsNiTgjLjm0o/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

At above image can see data without value also showing. I want to Query data with value only.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=QUERY(Paste!A:G, 
 "select A,B,C,D 
  where D <> 0 
    and D is not null
    and (B ='"&$C$6&"'
     or B ='"&$C$7&"' 
     or B ='"&$C$8&"'
     or B ='"&$C$9&"'
     or B ='"&$C$10&"' 
     or B ='"&$C$11&"') 
  order by D desc")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks ya for your help.